# Python Websocket Module with Proxies

Tags: python, module, proxy, websocket, proxies

I need a websocket module for python that has the ability to use proxies of any type. I will really appreciate any suggestions to use, I tried using websocket-client but it just generates endless errors for no reason.

Thanks.